# Dictionary of values from a function call?

Tags: python

I am running a bunch of experiments and I am constantly finding myself rewriting code in order to document the parameters that are being passed into a function. The main idea is to get a dictionary with the names of the variables that the function got and the values that it got (including default values). Here are some examples of what I am after

```
def foo(a, b, c=3, d=4):
    pass

foo(1,2)
  {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}

foo(1,2,5,6)
  {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':5, 'd':6}

foo(1,2,d=10)
  {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':10}
```

I have looked into using kwargs and the inspect module but I am not able to get the specified behavior.

Comment: `return {'a':a,'b':b,'c':c,'d':d}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need

```
def foo(a, b, c=3, d=4):
  return dict(locals())
```

Comment: That will definitely give the same dictionary but I am not familiar with the source code of locals method and the returned dictionary may or may not be safe for editing outside the method. So I added the dict() to be on the safer side.

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I wanted